# jenkins checkmarx plugin does not take envirnoment variables in exclude folder property?

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins, checkmarx

Im trying to pass the exclusions in checkmarx plugin by setting envirnoment variables. But the plugin does not seem to take envirnoment variables as parameter in Exclude folder field.

i have installed Checkmarx Plugin 7.2.1-26 and Jenkins ver. 1.596.3

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that the Checkmarx Jenkins plugin supports environment variables in the Project Name and Comment fields only.